# Stanford corenlp error while training NER models

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

Hi I am relatively new to Java and I am trying to follow [instructions](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.html#a) to train my own ner model .

while giving

```
java -cp stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -prop austen.prop
```

it  throws following error :

> Error: Could not find or load main class edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier

I am running this command from my corenlp directory keeping training data and prop file there.

PS: I have gone through few instructions/setting Path etc. doesn't seem to be working.

**Java Version :**

> java version "1.8.0_211"
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_211-b12)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.211-b12, mixed mode)

Answer (score 0):

This is a CLASSPATH error.  You need to run it with `-cp "*"` and it should be in the directory that contains the jar.